# K&R 2-3 htoi segmentation fault

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

Hi this is my first question here so I apologize if I didn't follow all the rules for posting. This is K&R exercise 2-3 and I'm getting a segmentation fault when compiling with GCC and I'm not familiar with the debugger to understand what's going on. I'd be grateful if anyone could glance over the code and help me with what went wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define HEX 16

unsigned int htoi(char s[]) {
    int i, len, n, rp, v;
    v = 0;

    if (s[0] == '0')
        if (s[1] == 'x' || s[1] == 'X')
           s[1] = '0';
    for (len = 0; len != '\0'; ++len) {
    }
    for (i = len; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9')
            n = s[i] - '0';
        else if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'F')
            n = s[i] - 'A' + 10;
        else if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'f')
            n = s[i] - 'a' + 10;

        rp = len - i;
        v += n * HEX^rp;
    }
    return v;
}

int main() {
    int test = htoi("0x1a9f");
    printf("%d\n", test);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I probably should have included the exercise question:

Exercise 2-3. Write a function htoi(s), which converts a string of hexadecimal digits (including an optional 0x or 0X) into its
equivalent integer value. The allowable digits are 0 through 9, a through f, and A through F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int test = htoi("0x1a9f");
```

passes the string literal `"0x1a9f"` to `htoi`.  This may exist in read-only memory and cannot be modified.  You therefore get undefined behaviour (with a crash a valid example of this) when you try to write to the string in the line

```
s[1] = '0';
```

The easiest fix is to copy the original string into a modifiable variable

```
char s[] = "0x1a9f";
int test = htoi(s);
```

As reported by Grijesh, further into `htoi`, you also read beyond the bounds of the string

```
for (i = len; i >= 0; --i)
```

should be:

```
for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; --i)
```

Comment: in addition also have out-of index, check my delete answer.

Comment: Good spot, I hadn't got that far through the code.  +1 on your answer (or would have been if you hadn't deleted it :))

Comment: because I have delete my answer, I except its pending :) Thanks! I want you to add that point.

Comment: thanks that got rid of the seg fault but there seems to be other bugs somewhere because i'm not getting the right output... i should be able to work out the rest though; again, thanks!

Comment: But what does `for (len = 0; len != '\0'; ++len) {}` accomplish? `len` is 0, and the ASCII value of '\0' is 0, so the loop will never execute. The next loop will initialize `i` to -1, and again the comparison will fail. Am I missing something?

Comment: youre right; i changed it to `for (len = 0; s[len] != '\0'; ++len) {}`

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the address of a string literal which is read-only. Doing the following will get rid of the segmentation fault.

```
char temp[] = "0x1a9f";
int test = htoi(temp);
```

Also:

```
v += n * HEX^rp;
```

Is `^` is the XOR operator and not the power operator. For power you need the `pow` function in `math.h`

Also:

`for (i = len; i >= 0; --i)` should be `for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; --i)` because the value of `len` goes out of the bound of the array. (Notified by @Grijesh Chauhan and @simonc)